Err: The requested module 'redux-thunk' does not provide an export named 'default'
I am currently learning redux and encountered an issue with importing redux-thunk in my Node.js project. I’m trying to set up middleware for my Redux store, but when I attempt to import redux-thunk, I get the following error:
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'redux-thunk' does not provide an export named 'default'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:214:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/modules/esm/module_loader:34:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)

Here’s a snippet of the code where the import is happening:
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import axios from 'axios';

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk.default));

function reducer(state={title:"Hello"},action){
    if(action.type === 'ch'){
        return {amount: action.payload};
    }
    return state;
}

async function change(dispatch,getState){
    const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/1');
    dispatch(changeUser(data.title))
}

function changeUser(value){
    return {type:'ch',payload:value}
}

store.dispatch(change);

console.log(store.getState());


I have set up package.json with "type": "module" to use ES module syntax. However, the error suggests that redux-thunk does not have a default export.
I tried importing thunk as a default export but got a SyntaxError.
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

Have you read the docs? thunk is a named export of redux-thunk - not the default export. import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk'; See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk?tab=readme-ov-file#manual-setup

i swear i had initially tried this  but that time it didnt work and showed some middleware error but now it worked.
i dont know what i had done that time
But thanks :)
